# exe file and robot framework

Tags: tkinter, robotframework, pyinstaller, python-multithreading

I did develop GUI using tkinter. It is used to choose test cases developed in robot framework and execute them. It is working fine when ran from pycharm ide. Then i converted it into exe file and included all the packages required. It is able to open the gui and i am able to select test case, but when test is executed it fails with following error. I am unable to debug and stuck at this point. How can i find the root cause for this issue

Error text : [ ERROR ] Execution stopped by user.

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wt0gM.png)

Comment: You need to provide a. Some code b. How you built the exe c. more detail from the error message. Nobody is going to be able to answer your question from the little information you've given so far.

Comment: @scotty3785 I have built exe using py2exe. i am new to building exe file. is there a way to get log  when exe file is executed?

Comment: I've never used py2exe so I don't know.

Comment: Please don't provide a picture of the error, because it's not searchable. Take the time to copy, paste, and format the error text.

Comment: @BryanOakley  "[ ERROR ] Execution stopped by user." This is the error text i get